# for (c in cars) - how does this for-loop work?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm writing a random generator that runs through an array, and randomizes the items in the array, then outputs it to HTML.

The below code works, however I repurposed it from various places and I'd like to understand how this for loop works, specifically, I don't know what `for (var c in cars)` checks for, and I've tried simply replacing each instance of `cars` in the loop, but it doesn't output anything then.

Here is a functioning codepen: http://codepen.io/npav/pen/xZXxqe

Just the JS:

```
var cars = 'Tarasenko,Steen,Backes,Stastny,Jaskin,Ott,Brodziak,Upshall,Rattie,Fabbri,Brouwer, Berglund'.split(',');

cars.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });

for (var c in cars) {
    var newElement = document.createElement('div');
    newElement.id = cars[c]; newElement.className = "car";
    newElement.innerHTML = cars[c];
    document.getElementById("forwards").appendChild(newElement);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: It cycles over `cars`, referring to the current value index (0,1,2,...) as `c`. See also [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Comment: For..in iterates over the enumerable values of the object. In this case, that is the index of the array. It can also be the properties of a more generic object. Here's the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @sampson Thanks, so if I changed `var cars` to `var players`, along with all the other instances of `cars`, it would then cycle through `players'?

Comment: I was wondering how this code even works. But hey, there's actually a `.split(',');` at the end of cars. That explains everything.

Comment: @npav42 Yes, based on this code. If you change `cars` to `players`, you've not changed the structure of the code. Only a variable name.

Comment: @sampson just tried and everything works, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So, unlike a standard `for` loop that uses a counter, this goes through all the enumerable keys of the object. There are different ways to do this. The spec, [ECMA 262/51/#sec-12.6.4, "The for-in Statement"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4) has this to say (some links and highlighting lost in quotation):

> The production IterationStatement : for ( var VariableDeclarationNoIn
>   in Expression ) Statement is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let varName be the result of evaluating VariableDeclarationNoIn.
> 2. Let exprRef be the result of evaluating the Expression.
> 3. Let experValue be GetValue(exprRef).
> 4. If experValue is null or undefined, return (normal, empty, empty).
> 5. Let obj be ToObject(experValue).
> 6. Let V = empty.
> 7. Repeat
>
>    a. Let P be the name of the next property of obj whose [[Enumerable]] attribute is true. If there is no such property, return
>      (normal, V, empty).
>
>    b. Let varRef be the result of evaluating varName as if it were an
>      Identifier Reference (11.1.2); it may be evaluated repeatedly.
>       c. Call PutValue(varRef, P).
>
>    d. Let stmt be the result of evaluating Statement.
>
>    e. If stmt.value is not empty, let V = stmt.value.
>
>    f. If stmt.type is break and stmt.target is in the current label
>      set, return (normal, V, empty).
>
>    g. If stmt.type is not continue || stmt.target is not in the current
>      label set, then
>
>    i. If stmt is an abrupt completion, return stmt.
>
> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties (..., step 7.a in the second) is not specified.

Note that I didn't post the entire section, and that the algorithm is different based on if you do `for(x in y)` or `for(var x in y)`

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet.. Your use of for-in loop is wrong. for-in loops through the properties of an object and doesn't necessarily mean that the object should be an array. Please see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

for (var prop in obj) {
  console.log("obj." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
}

// Output:
// "obj.a = 1"
// "obj.b = 2"
// "obj.c = 3"
```

Based on your code, I would suggest using a for-loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    var newElement = document.createElement('div');
    newElement.id = cars[i]; newElement.className = "car";
    newElement.innerHTML = cars[i];
    document.getElementById("forwards").appendChild(newElement);
}
```